# What is the canonical way to get files outside of a git repo, into a repo, without moving them?

Tags: git

## The Problem

I've got an application that, unhelpfully enough, stores some of its configuration files in a separate location from all of its other configuration files. I found this long after setting the application up, and all of the stuff in the "main" config file directory is being managed by git.

`../app/config/        <-- git controlled`

`../app/utility/config <-- not`

Ideally, I would be able to just add the stuff in `../utility/config` to the first repo and be done with it. Unfortunately, git makes this seemingly simple operation somewhat complicated.

---

- It does not follow symbolic links, meaning I can't just link `utility/config` into the first repo. This would be ideal, but...
- Hardlinks don't allow for directories, and making the folder and hardlinking each file into into it sucks.
- Changing `GIT_WORK_TREE` to be one level higher could work, but then I'm forced to use that command for the remainder of time if I want most git commands to work.
- `mount --bind` would work, but seems awfully hackish, and would be annoying and error-prone to duplicate on another developer's machine.
- Moving the config files is a non-option, as they're referenced by the third party application.
- Creating a new repo and using submodules would work, [but submodules are bad, mmkay?](https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/)

---

## The Question

Are there any other easy options for getting these files into the existing repo without moving either the files or the repo?

Comment: The problem is that Git is not a packaging tool. Either make `app/` the repository so that `config` and `utility/config` are both subdirectories, or use a real packaging tool to install from a Git repository to your production server.

Comment: Is the goal to put the new files under revision control?  Or to reference the external files for build and run?   If the latter, just locally or to distribute to others (e.g., third party software/ tools that your current repo depends upon)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do symbolic link from outside to the git-managed dir, e.g.

```
mv app/utility/config app/config/app_utility_config
ln -s app/utility/config app/config/app_utility_config
cd app/config
git add app_utility_config
git commit -m "tracking the app/utility/config"
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, moving the files is not possible. The first line of your command causes the app to break.

Comment: do you mean you don't have a downtime window ever?

Comment: No, i mean the app expects the config files to be in a certain location under its directory - moving them is impossible, nor will it follow the symlink.

Comment: Then your only option is (r)sync I guess.